# Exposing useState setter function to global scope in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm curious if I could do something like this:

```
const [panelActive, setPanelActive] = useState(false);
(globalThis as any).setPanelActive = setPanelActive;

useEffect(() => console.log(panelActive), [panelActive])
```

For some reason, `useEffect` is not getting triggered when I call `setPanelActive` function from outside.
 Should I create some sort of wrapper or context provider in order to make it work?

Comment: can you provide a complete example?

Comment: You're mutating the globalThis object, and React doesn't see the change, because its reference is stable. You don't need to pass out a setter, because you can just bring in the value on props. But if you do need to pass out a setter, you'll need to pass in a callback that you can call with the setter, and then the setter can set the value at an appropriate place.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! I have a react app and some non react API code. I'm trying to make a bridge between react and that API if that's even possible.

Comment: @GentleSir in this case you can think of emitting an event with the API and listen to those events from your react app and just update the state you want based on the event and event data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for participating. After some research on what [@hatana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13488990/hatana) mentioned, i found a solution - the [event bus](https://github.com/DawChihLiou/eventbus-demo). It does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you expected `globalThis.setPanelActive` to work as `setPanelActive` with the assignment you are doing, then you are wrong, hooks are designed to work within the scope of a component in this case you have to use a [context](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext) on a higher lever something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  export const PanelConext = createContext(); // import createContext
  const [panelActive, setPanelActive] = useState(false);
  //...

  useEffect(() => console.log(panelActive), [panelActive])

  
  return (
    <PanelConext.Provider value={{ panelActive, setPanelActive}}>
      //..
    </PanelConext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```js
const Component = () => {
  const { panelActive, setPanelActive} = useContext(PanelContext); // import `PanelContext`from App and `useContext` from react
  //...
};
```

now when you use `setPanelActive` from any component `useEffect` should fire